# about transaction virtual database of jboss, how to configure, I want to use this transaction

Tags: teiid

I want use the transaction in the virtual database procedure, but I cannot find the relative statement, I think the statement about transaction in the virtual database handbook is less, and I can not get useful information from handbook.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
BEGIN ATOMIC
// do stuff here
END
```

see http://teiid.github.io/teiid-documents/13.1.x/content/reference/r_compound-statement.html